# Will DHCP server give me always same IP?

Tags: networking, ip, esp8266, ipv4, dhcp

I have question on DHCP server in home router. I have founded, that I have same IP address in my notebook for some time. I don't know, how long it last, but it is probably few weeks at least. Will DHCP server ever change my local IP if i will still connecting to that Wi-Fi?
I am asking, because I am working on home automation system and I don't know if i had to keep care about checking if my devices has same IP...Because there will be server, which will remember IP of its clients (lets say ESP8266 modules). Must I periodically check IP address (in my modules) and send new IP to server (in case of change)? Or DHCP server will not change IP address of my modules, connected to that DHCP server? And what about situation when ESP8266 module will disconnect (lets say it will be off for few days) - is it common to get different or same IP from DHCP after connection again?

Thanks!

Comment: Mine have been consistent for years on end.

Comment: on most routers with DHCP you can reserve a IP for MAC

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be reserving IP address for your ESP8266 modules in your DHCP server that they always receive the same IPs.

With regards to your questions:

1. My routers DHCP server saves clients and keep information about them unless it is deleted explicitly or number of saved clients gets larger than number of addresses available. It serves always the same IP to saved clients. Obviously it depends on the router and might be different in your case.
2. I'd not check for IPs manually, I'd rather reserve the IPs for the modules as said above.
3. If your DHCP server stores client information it will give the same IPs to your modules upon reconnect. Otherwise not it won't be necessary the case.
4. If you use or consider using MQTT server (my preferred way :) ) for your home automation (it has integration in many systems like e.g. Home Assistant) you won't need to care about IP addresses of your modules at all you'd only need to fix IP of the MQTT server.
5. Another option can be addressing your modules (or/and server) using host name instead of IPs. If you develop n Arduino [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2826) might be helpful.

Comment: nice answer, but the question so the answer is off-topic on this Q&A site about codding